# Giving weight to a delta

Tags: excel, weighted-average, sumproduct

I have to analyze a delta impact for different categories but we need to focus on only with the highest priority. Example:

| Col.A(dollar value) | Col.B (Forecast) | Col.C (Actual) | Col.D (delta) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 50 | 30 | 20 |
| 60 | 40 | 10 | 50 |

Is sumproduct the only best method? Also there are different attributes by which I need to look at the data

Comment: It's not clear how to reproduce your problem. What is your expected output and how do you currently calculate your delta column?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: 2 data points are there Given time and Taken Time, we would want to understand the deltas by different categories, but the condition is to focus on deltas by number of deliveries. Which means no point in analyzing a delta of 60 where the deliveries are 20 in a month whereas I would want to focus on a delta of 40 were monthly deliveries are 4000. Sorting of delta between 2 sets of data keeping a 3rd data set as sorting criteria